# Enquiry Form not submitting

Tags: javascript, validation, return

I have some required fields on my EnquiryForm. I did have a alert box prompting the user of the errors. But i have since removed it and inputed the errors within the text fields.

Now I'm unsure how to code the return false once all conditions have been met.

Validation works fine, form just doesn't submit.

I'm a newbie to javascripting so appologies in advance.....

Here's my code:

```
// Enquiry Form Validation
function enquiryFormValidation() {

// Setting Variables

var errormessage = "";

var ufirstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
var usurname = document.getElementById("surname"); 
var uaddress = document.getElementById("address");
var upostcode = document.getElementById("postcode");
var uemail = document.getElementById("email");
var uhearabout = document.getElementById("where");
var fday = document.getElementById("fday");
var fmonth = document.getElementById("month");
var fyear = document.getElementById("year");
var ftype = document.getElementById("ftype");
var garrival = document.getElementById("garrival");
var fend = document.getElementById("fend");


if (ufirstname.value == "(e.g. John)") {
ufirstname.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
ufirstname.style.color = "red" ;
ufirstname.value = "Firstname Required"
 }

if (usurname.value == "(e.g. Smith)") {
usurname.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
usurname.style.color = "red" ;
usurname.value = "Surname Required"
 }

if (uaddress.value == "(e.g. 101 Party Street, Wellington)") {
uaddress.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
uaddress.style.color = "red" ;
uaddress.value = "Address Required"
 }

if (upostcode.value == "(e.g. TF1 7HU)") {
upostcode.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
upostcode.style.color = "red" ;
upostcode.value = "Postcode Required"
 }   

if (uemail.value == "(e.g. lets_party@glimmer-nights.co.uk)") {
uemail.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
uemail.style.color = "red" ;
uemail.value = "Email Address Required"
 }   

if (uhearabout.options[uhearabout.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
uhearabout.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
uhearabout.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (fday.options[fday.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
fday.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
fday.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (fmonth.options[fmonth.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
fmonth.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
fmonth.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (fyear.options[fyear.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
fyear.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
fyear.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (ftype.options[ftype.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
ftype.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
ftype.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (garrival.options[garrival.selectedIndex].value == "hh:mm") {
garrival.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
garrival.style.color = "red" ;
 }

if (fend.options[fend.selectedIndex].value == "hh:mm") {
fend.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
fend.style.color = "red" ;
 }

 {
return false;    
 }

} // End of enquiryForm-validation function
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Depending on how you call that function, it should return `false` to _stop_ submission, and return `true` to _allow_ submission. So perhaps add a flag `formValid = true` and then inside each of your if statements add `formValid = false` and then you can use `return formValid;` at the end of your function.

Comment: No, no error messages. The validation is working I will add

Comment: So if I were to edit the false statement to true that should do the trick?

Comment: If you remove the return false it would submit every time even when validation fails. Note also that if the user leaves all of the fields blank and you change them to red, and then the user corrects some but not all of them and tries again your function will leave the previously-incorrect-but-now-correct fields as red.

Comment: Am i thinking this right, do I have to include return false to the end of each if statement?

Comment: If you include return false inside each if statement then it will stop after the first invalid field, which means the function won't turn _all_ invalid fields red. Do what I mentioned in my first comment, above.

Comment: I am aware of the inputs remaining red, I have edited this in a separate onblur / onfocus function

Comment: Apologies im new to Java - how do I implement a formValid = true flag?

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, I have got it working now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor this.

For example

```
var valFields = { 
  "firstname":"Please enter a first name",
  "surname":"Please enter a surname",
  .
  .
   "fend":"please enter a valid time in HH:mm format"
}// note no comma after the last

function validate() {
  for (var fieldID in valFields) {
    var field = document.getElementById(fieldID);
    field.className ="normal"; // for example
    if (
      (field.type=="text" && field.value==field.defaultValue) ||
      (field.type=="select" && field.selectedIndex<1) // and so on
    ) {
      field.className="red" // for example
      alert(valFields[fieldID]);
      return false;// cancel submit
    }
  }
  return true;// allow submit
}
```

To use

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Which should really be set in the head instead of inline but I am on an iPad and tired of typing